# How to append permissions of each role in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to append data into HTML using JS. I have roles and their respective permissions, data are fetching using laravel ORM.
I am using nested each Jquery function to append permissions but didn't get a solution.
Please guide me on how can I append data into a table?

[image]

> JS:

```
$( document ).ready(async function() {

    var id = localStorage.getItem('userid');
    var users = '';
    var roles = '';

    if (id != null) {
        await $.ajax({
            url: base_url_local + `/roles/${id}`,
            type: 'get',
            success: function (response) {
                // users = response.users;
                // roles = response.roles;
                $(response.roles).each(function (index, role) {
                    $('#roles_tr').append(`<tr>
                       <td>${role.name}</td>
                       <td class="tagCursor">
                           <span>${JSON.stringify(role.permissions)}</span>
                       </td>
                    </tr>`)},
                );
            },

        });
    }
});
```

> Response from Laravel ORM (Database):

[image]

Comment: How do you want to present the permissions? A list of their names? (e.g. `show dashboard`, `manage expense` etc.)

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the names of permissions and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concat them to one string

```js
$(response.roles).each(function (index, role) {
  $('#roles_tr').append(`<tr>
     <td>${role.name}</td>
     <td class="tagCursor">
         <span>${role.permissions.map(p => p.name).join()}</span>
     </td>
  </tr>`)},
);
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)